# ssh to localhost displays "Connection closed by remote host"

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sshd

I had ssh installed and working. I ran `sudo chmod -R 777 /var` and it stopped working. I changed permissions with `sudo chmod -R 700 /var` but that didn't make it work again.

When I do `ssh -v localhost` I get this output:

```
rajat@ubuntu:/$ ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/rajat/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rajat/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rajat/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rajat/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rajat/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rajat/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
rajat@ubuntu:/$
```

Comment: Lesson learned: don't bloody do that. Why on Earth would messing up permissions all over `/var` not break things, and how did you think messing them up some more would help at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenSSH is very picky when it comes to file and directory permissions and ownership. The only directory under `/var` that it touches, at least on RHEL/CentOS, is the `/var/empty/sshd` directory, which it does a `chroot` to if `UsePrivilegeSeparation` is set to yes.

Set this in your `sshd_config` file:

```
UsePrivilegeSeparation no
```

And restart sshd, and see if it works. If that does it, it's likely the permissions/ownership on `/var/empty/sshd` that's causing the problem.

Comment: well, You replied too late :(. But thankfully I was working in a virtual machine(vmware) and I ended up copying all my work to a repository and then going back a snapshot in my virtual machine and doing a `svn update`. But since this is the only answer, I'm going to mark it correct.

Comment: But is it correct @prongs ?  That's why you should mark it as correct, not because it's the only answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If anyone runs into a similar error message when attempting to connect to a Ubuntu VM running on VirtualBox, set a 2nd network adapter as "bridged" in network settings, and set up port forwarding on "NAT" to 22.